# Print only HTML Table from page

Tags: html, css, printing, html-table

I have a page that has a lot of elements on it - Buttons, Tiles, Tables, Lists, etc. I am wanting to only print ONE of the HTML tables when I click my print button.... I am needing to do this via `css` and `html`, what is the bets way to accomplish this? I have the following, but this prints the entire page:

**CSS**

```
 <style media="screen">
    .noPrint {
        display: block;
    }

    .yesPrint {
        display: block !important;
    }
</style>

<style media="print">
    .noPrint {
        display: none;
    }

    .yesPrint {
        display: block !important;
    }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="table-responsive yesPrint">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
             <thead>
                 <tr>
                    <th style="text-align: left; font-size: 15px;">Number</th>
                    <th style="text-align: left; font-size: 15px;">Caller</th>
                    <th style="text-align: left; font-size: 15px;">Description</th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <td style="text-align: left; font-size: 13px;">Number</td>
                           <td style="text-align: left; font-size: 13px;">Name</td>
                           <td style="text-align: left; font-size: 13px;">Here is the short description</td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="button" onclick="window.print()"/>
</div>
```

Comment: You do have `noPrint` in your other table's container, right? It's not in your sample HTML.

Comment: A child, even with `display: block`, inside a parent with `display: none` will still be hidden.

Comment: @Katana314 I do... and it is still printing the entire page - all elements, not just all tables

Comment: use media query for printing one element in printing media query, that will help you

Comment: Good point @DK3, will do this